# pipe contact form 7 calculate plugin

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Не работает pipe в contact form 7  с расширением калькулятор https://wordpress.org/plugins/cost-calculator-contact-form-7/.

Вот это значение не считает "Да|12000" "Нет|0"

```
<label>Компьютеры:[rangeslider rangeslider-627 min:1 max:50 step:1 
color:#000000 calslider:left caltoltip:top]</label>

<label>Серверы:[rangeslider rangeslider-600 min:1 max:8 step:1 
color:#000000 calslider:left caltoltip:top]</label>

Поддержка удаленно(12000)
[checkbox checkbox-654  exclusive "Да|12000" "Нет|0"]


Итого: [calculator calculator-693 "rangeslider-627*3000+ rangeslider- 
600*8000+checkbox-654)"]
```

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Какое расширение "калькулятор"? Что значит не работает? Код оформи нормально.

Answer (score 1):

`checkbox` не попадает в расчет потому что вы добавили параметр `exclusive` для которого поле `name` в теге `input` будет иметь значение `name="checkbox-654"`, в то время как плагин ожидает имя следующей структуры `name="checkbox-654[]"`. Вы можете либо убрать параметр `exclusive` либо изаменить тип поля с  `checkbox` на `radio`

Код из плагина для выборки чекбоксов

```
jQuery("input[name='"+match[0]+"[]']:checked")
```